# Which Webserver shall i take for High-Traffic Python Web-Pages?

Tags: python, web, nginx, apache2, webserver

We want to write our Webapps in Python for High-Traffic use **(800 req/sec)**, but we don't know which Webserver and module are the best one.

We actually think **Apache2 + mod_wsgi** is a good option, but maybe Apache2 + FastCGI or Nginx + mod_wsgi oder FastCGI could be better.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is not a good question for stackoverflow, however I'd give a shot to nginx + uwsgi.

Comment: I'm sorry.. what's a good question for Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with - Apache2(mod_wsgi) + Nginx(Proxy) . Where Nginx will be serving the static content and directing the dynamic content request to Apache2 server . This will improve the performance of your application .

Comment: Thanks for this answer.. we'll try this!

Comment: Here a manual for installing the nginx as reverse proxy! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org) + [Nginx Proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)